# jQuery UI - Resizing element A does not make neighbor element B smaller?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery-ui-1.12.1.

I have 3 areas placed horizontal on the screen:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item" id="menu">
        <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="browser">
        <!--Canvas is added in here-->
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="controls">
        <p>Controls</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I resize the #menu div to become wider, I want the #browser div width to become smaller, but it stays the same width.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').resizable({
        handles: 'e',
        minWidth: 100,
        stop: function( event, ui ) { 
            console.log("Done resizing");
            console.log( "Browser width: " + $('#browser').width() );
        }
    });
});
```

The #browser div stays the same width, but I want it to get smaller as #menu get's larger.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a bit of manual code:

```
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var oldWidth = ui.originalSize.width;
        var newWidth = ui.size.width;
        var difference = newWidth - oldWidth;
        var browserElem = $('#browser');
        var currentBrowserWidth = browserElem.width();
        var newBrowserWidth = currentBrowserWidth - difference;
        browserElem.width(newBrowserWidth);
    }
```

However, in my case, the browser div contains a canvas running ThreeJS, and resizing the browser div results in odd behavior, hence I'll rather keep it at it's previous state.